# Should “improve at the following fronts” be followed by problems or solutions?

Tags: meaning-in-context, writing-style, tech-writing, writing-advice

I am writing a technology report. It starts with an analysis of the current problems in the system. As a summary I have a paragraph to list all the problems in bullets. I use this sentence to start the summary:

> We can improve the system at the following fronts.

After this sentence is a list of problems.

My colleague edited the report and changed the tone of the bullet list from problems to solutions. For example, he changed

> The tightly coupled sub-systems are hard to adapt change.

to

> Reduce the tight coupling between sub-systems.

This makes me wonder what the natural interpretation of

> We can improve the system at the following fronts.

actually is.

To me, *at the following fronts* indicates that what follows is the stuff to be improved upon, and so it should be a list of problems.

But to my colleague, what follows should be the list of improvement actions.

What do you think?

Comment: Grammatically, I think either a list of problems and a list of solutions is acceptable. However, a list of solutions may be much better for other reasons. I suspect this change had nothing to do with grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Front* is a metaphor drawn from soldiering: the *front line*, where opposed armies meet. *At the front* is a tactical position: it means “stationed in the front line”. Consequently, you cannot be *at* more than one front at once. And your colleague may very well take being *at a front* to imply a concern with the tactical actions to be taken there.

What you mean, I think, is a slightly different metaphor, a strategic one: a country which is fighting simultaneously against two or more enemies in different places is said to be fighting **on** multiple fronts. So what you want is:

> We can improve the system on the following fronts.

This however begs the question. You want to list the problems; your colleague wants to list the solutions. I suggest the two of you decide which it is you want to address at this juncture, and **name that explicitly** instead of resorting to dubiously relevant metaphor:

> Here are the problems which need to be addressed: ... *OR*
>   Here are the actions we propose to take: ... *OR EVEN*
>   Here are the problems which need to be addressed, and the solutions we propose: